# Using the stlplus::stlplus() function gives a weird error

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series and I'm trying to use the `stlplus()` function from the `stlplus` package.
The `ts()` object is ok, but the `stlplus()` gives me a weird error:

```
serie <- ts(Dados_PFI$PFI, start = c(1991, 1), end = c(1999, 12), frequency = 12)

stlPFI <- stlplus(serie, t.window = 7, s.window = 2, inner = 2, outer = 10)
stlPFI
Error in yaImpute::ann(ref = as.matrix(x2), target = as.matrix(m), tree.type = "kd", : error: k must be int > 0
```

I don't have any `NA` values or something wrong with the data itself.
When I use `stats::stl()` the code works OK, but I have to use `stlplus()`.

Comment: somehow, k (the number of neighbors, default = 1) in [yalmpute](https://rdrr.io/cran/yaImpute/src/R/ann.R) is getting set to k < 1, see around line #16 for the error.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I never needed `yaImpute`. I think `stlplus` is calling him, but I can't figure out why `k` is changing his default value.

Comment: Your, `s.window` should be odd and isn't, No default value provided. Just reading.

Comment: Perhaps, use , ...) to state k = 1 even though it appears to have a default value, but might not in stlplus, vs stats::stl, with all the back and forth to C that is supposed to happen in stlplus. Is as much as I can imagine.

Comment: Good observation, this is in the article of STL algorithm.